# Android Simple imageView Widget with two picture

Tags: android, android-studio, android-imageview

I'm trying to make a widget that consists of one imageView and when you tap it, it changes to another image and also when I tab on Web button it supposes to open the browser and open a site.

My problem is, is that there are no good Tutorials on how to make widgets, so I don't know how to do this.

I have already made a widget layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#09C"
android:padding="@dimen/widget_margin">


<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:onClick="Web"
    android:text="Web"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="110dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="6dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:onClick="onClick"
    android:text="Image" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button2"
    android:onClick="Music"
    android:text="Music" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button3"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:src="@drawable/fox"
    android:onClick="widgetOnClick"
    android:clickable="true"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/fox2"
    />
```

I've tried to make some code in my .java file, but that only open Web when I comment out everything about imageView

```
void updateAppWidget(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
                     int appWidgetId) {


    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("http://www.wykop.pl"));
    PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    RemoteViews views1 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
    views1.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button, pending);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views1);

    intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, 0);
    RemoteViews views2 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
    views2.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button2, pendingIntent);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views2);
}




@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    // There may be multiple widgets active, so update all of them
    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        updateAppWidget(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds[i]);
    }
}


@Override
public void onEnabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the first widget is created
}

@Override
public void onDisabled(Context context) {
    // Enter relevant functionality for when the last widget is disabled
}

public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
    super.onReceive(context, intent);

    final AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
    RemoteViews views1 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);
    final RemoteViews views2 = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.new_app_widget);


    if (intent.getAction().equals(intent)) {
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context, NewAppWidget.class), views1);
    }

    if (intent.getAction().equals(intent)) {
        imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                imageView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context, NewAppWidget.class), views2);
            }
        });

        imageView2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View view) {
                imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(new ComponentName(context, NewAppWidget.class), views2);
            }
        });
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Your code is no complete, check your project and paste everything because it looks like something is missing